# Using Closure compiler with Underscore.js _.template

Tags: google-closure-compiler, underscore.js

Is there any way to compile Underscore.js templates on the server **and** get the Closure compiler to work with the generated code?

The main problem is that `_.template`:

```js
_.template = function(str, data) {
    var c  = _.templateSettings;
    var tmpl = 'var __p=[],print=function(){__p.push.apply(__p,arguments);};' +
        'with(obj||{}){__p.push(\'' +
        str.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
        .replace(/'/g, "\\'")
        .replace(c.interpolate, function(match, code) {
            return "'," + code.replace(/\\'/g, "'") + ",'";
        })
        .replace(c.evaluate || null, function(match, code) {
            return "');" + code.replace(/\\'/g, "'")
                .replace(/[\r\n\t]/g, ' ') + "__p.push('";
        })
        .replace(/\r/g, '\\r')
        .replace(/\n/g, '\\n')
        .replace(/\t/g, '\\t')
        + "');}return __p.join('');";
    var func = new Function('obj', tmpl);
    return data ? func(data) : func;
};
```

generates JavaScript with a with-statement in it. The two obvious routes are:

1. modify Underscore.js's `_.template` not to generate withs
2. coerce Closure into playing nice

Is the second option possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the JS engines perform better without "with", so if generating it without "with" is an option that is likely the best solution.

Otherwise your options depend on whether you are hoping to using Closure Compilers ADVANCED mode.  In SIMPLE mode, the compiler won't rename your properties on the template, and will assume that any undeclared variable are globals.  So as long are your template object isn't causing any local variables to be shadowed it might "just work".

Comment: Yes, I am aiming for advanced compilation. My reluctance on reworking _.template is that it is library code that is periodically updated -- a maintenance issue.

Comment: Depending on your needs you might consider using Closure Templates which are designed to work with ADVANCED compilation.